# Visual studio 2010 unable to debug web application. Maybe corrupt installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharepoint, web-applications

I can't debug my Sharepoint 2010 project. Visual Studio 2010 shows me the following error message:

*Unable to attach to he process. An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80040154). If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel.*

I experienced this problem some days ago for the first time.
At first repairing helped, but after a little time the error occurred again.
I have tried restarting computer, too, after which the problem was gone for only a little time.
I have uninstalled/reinstalled visual studio, but still no success.

How can I solve this problem, I have no idea about the reason.

**EDIT:** I have noticed that the problem occurs only when I try to debug a workflow code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past and solved it by ensuring I'm compiling the code to x64. Check your settings in Visual Studio. SharePoint is 64bit only.

Good Luck.

Comment: I have set it to Any CPU and it has worked fine. Besides, I don't have any deployment issue, too. Does it affect debug anyway?

Comment: Set it to x64, yes it affects debug. You are running in a x64 only environment. It won't debug until you change the build options.

Comment: Since I haven't got another answer to this question for a long time, I'm accepting this one. It may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the javascript debugger on a web project, and I got a similar error message.  The fix was: Closed all instances of Visual Studio. I threw away the app in inetmgr, and re-opened visual studio with my solution that has my web app. It re-created the virtual directory on opening.  Javascript debugger started working again.

Comment: Since I wrote this, I had this problem come back one more time, and I found I had many instances of msbuild mysteriously running.